# InvalidDataException thrown while using mp3agic in an android project

Tags: java, android

I am using [mp3agic]:http://mpatric.github.io/mp3agic/ in my android project to retrieve mp3 id3 tags but its throwing this

```
10-17 19:07:01.894: W/System.err(11659): com.mpatric.mp3agic.InvalidDataException: No mpegs frames found
```

My Java code implementation is here

```
File AllSong=new File(MEDIA_PATH);
if(AllSong.listFiles(new FileNameFilter()).length>0){
for(File asong:AllSong.listFiles(new FileNameFilter())){
try {
Mp3File mp3=new Mp3File(asong.getPath());
} catch (UnsupportedTagException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidDataException e) {
System.out.println("invalid:"+e.getDetailedMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();}
```

But when i create Mp3File for particular file like

```
Mp3File mp3=new Mp3File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Hero.mp3");
```

the error not thrown. I couldn't figureout the reason. Help.

Comment: `No mpegs frames found` means that the File is not an mp3-file. Are you sure the path is right?

Comment: According to my FileNameFilter() all files has .mp3 extension. Can there be any other reason for error?

Comment: If it's an .mp3 file, I don't know what the problem is. But to ensure, did you try to print out the path?

Comment: yeah I tried printing out all the files.They are all present in as "/mnt/sdcard/**.mp3"

Comment: The error means just what it says. When you create the Mp3File object, it scans the file to find the first mp3 frame. If it doesn't find any, it throws the error you are seeing. It means your file is not an mp3 file. Just because the file extension is .mp3 it does not make it a valid mp3.

Comment: So if my file has .mp3 extension but it is not valid mp3 file.how to get rid of it?

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution for InvalidDataException: No mpegs frames found ? I have more than 1500 crashes for my android app with this exception. I am unable to reproduce this and stuck in solving it.

Comment: Actually Mine problem was due to some files with `.mp3` extension are not actually mp3 file.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest. That's what was messing me up.